# JSON-API - use custom HTTP header or meta information for 'product-code'

Tags: api-design, json-api

The company I work for has several products that consume shared APIs. Previously we've passed the 'product-code' as a custom HTTP header. It's generally only used for things like determining a product-specific API key, or included in certain log messages, etc. It's generally not persisted to a database.

Recently we've started adopting the JSON-API spefification for building APIs.

Would the recommendation be to use [meta information](https://jsonapi.org/format/#auto-id--meta-information) to specify the 'product-code', or to keep this as a custom HTTP header?

Cheers.

Comment: Is this `product-code` currently sent as a request or response HTTP header? Is it set by the client on the request or by the server on the response? Is it resource specific? I mean does one resource (unique combination of type and ID) have always the same value for `product-code`?

Comment: it's on the request. It's probably something that could be included in all operations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would the recommendation be to use meta information to specify the
> 'product-code', or to keep this as a custom HTTP header?

It's totally fine to use a custom HTTP header with an API which implements [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/).

The `meta` property allows to include meta information on per JSON:API document, per resource object or per relationship of a resource object basis. It can only be included in requests and response, which include a JSON:API document.

Your use case does not fit well with the `meta` property. If I got it right from your comment it should be possible to include the `product-code` information with every request. But not all requests have a JSON:API document, in which `meta` section you could include it. For example neither fetch (`GET`) nor delete requests for resources include a JSON:API document as request body.